# Show data source / JAAS password in websphere 8.5?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I have a Data Source in a dev instance of WAS 8.5.  I have no clue who knows this password.  Can I show the password somehow on the websphere console?

---

[image: How can I show this password ?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. But you can look in the `security.xml` file in the `%PROFILE_ROOT%\config...\` for jaas aliases and decode password if you really need it.

Comment: Do mean decrypt?

Comment: @MrSmith It is not encrypted, its encoded (xor), thats why decode not decrypt.

Comment: found a website to do the decode: https://strelitzia.net/wasXORdecoder/wasXORdecoder.html.    thank you.